# Flash control not finding swf flv player file

Tags: html, flash, flv, swfobject

I am about to give up on Flash altogether (unfortunately 15% of the paying visitors to site are using IE7 which has no support for HTML5). I have an SWF file that is an FLV player called "player_flv_maxi.swf" that works only if I have a separate config.xml file.

The problem is, I absolutely have to ditch the config file altogether, however, the player simply won't work without it (I've scoured the Internet to find another player, but every single one has some serious bugs in them - every example I've seen either uses "player_flv.swf" or some variant, and other examples use one called "player.swf" which does not seem to be anywhere in existence on the web.

I have three files in a folder called "IM" off the root website -
"CommercialTacTilesJan2014.flv",
"CommercialTacTilesJan2014.jpg",
"player_flv_maxi.swf"

All three files are accessible from the website if you type them in, however, no matter how I change the settings (include or exclude the IM/ in the path(s), nothing shows up, not even the jpeg). Maybe this player ONLY works with a config file, I don't know. I've double checked the MIME types on the server for flv, swf and they are correct.

Here's the markup (I've gone through it many times, but can't see anything wrong):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <br>TEST 123<br><br>
    
<object id="FlashControl2" width="560px" height="320px" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0">
<param name="movie" value="IM/player_flv_maxi.swf">
<param name="quality" value="best">
<param name="play" value="false">
<param name="loop" value="false">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="scale" value="default">
<param name="flv" value="IM/CommercialTacTilesJan2014.flv" />
<param name="width" value="560" />
<param name="height" value="320" />
<param name="autoplay" value="0" />
<param name="autoload" value="0" />
<param name="buffer" value="5" />
<param name="buffermessage" value="" />
<param name="buffercolor" value="000000" />
<param name="bufferbgcolor" value="ffffff" />
<param name="buffershowbg" value="1" />
<param name="title" value="Commercial TacTiles Jan2014" />
<param name="titlesize" value="20" />
<param name="titlecolor" value="000000" />
<param name="margin" value="5" />
<param name="srt" value="0" />
<param name="srtcolor" value="000000" />
<param name="srtbgcolor" value="ffffff" />
<param name="srtsize" value="11" />
<param name="showstop" value="1" />
<param name="showvolume" value="1" />
<param name="showtime" value="1" />
<param name="showplayer" value="autohide" />
<param name="showloading" value="autohide" />
<param name="showfullscreen" value="1" />
<param name="showswitchsubtitles" value="0" />
<param name="showmouse" value="autohide" />
<param name="startimage" value="IM/CommercialTacTilesJan2014.jpg" />
<param name="playercolor" value="ffffff" />
<param name="loadingcolor" value="656565" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff" />
<param name="bgcolor1" value="ffffff" />
<param name="bgcolor2" value="ffffff" />
<param name="buttoncolor" value="000000" />
<param name="buttonovercolor" value="c2c2c2" />
<param name="slidercolor1" value="898989" />
<param name="slidercolor2" value="000000" />
<param name="sliderovercolor" value="c2c2c2" />
<param name="loadonstop" value="0" />
<param name="onclick" value="playpause" />
<param name="onclicktarget" value="_blank" />
<param name="ondoubleclick" value="fullscreen" />
<param name="ondoubleclicktarget" value="_blank" />
<param name="playertimeout" value="1500" />
<param name="videobgcolor" value="000000" />
<param name="volume" value="100" />
<param name="shortcut" value="1" />
<param name="playeralpha" value="100" />
<param name="phpstream" value="0" />
<param name="srturl" value="video.srt" />
<param name="top1" value="0" />
<param name="showiconplay" value="1" />
<param name="iconplaycolor" value="ffffff" />
<param name="iconplaybgcolor" value="dddddd" />
<param name="iconplaybgalpha" value="25" />
<param name="showtitleandstartimage" value="1" />
</object>
    

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your server's logs to see what the player app IS requesting from your server?

Comment: Yes, I figured out that it was that the player must have absolute paths. With the config file, it supports relative paths - go figure (If I were rich enough to afford Adobe's software, I'd make my own dang player w/o having to guess at a black box of someone else's madness)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the author's website (after going through "FreeStudio's" documentation and typing in some key words into google): http://flv-player.net/

Without the config.xml file, the flv parameter and startimage parameter do not work at all.
Instead, you have to use the FlashVars parameter and url encode the flv and startimage parameters with the FULL path (relative paths do not work) of both the video and cover picture like so:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv=http%3A//www.mywebsite.com/IM/CommercialTacTilesJan2014.flv&amp;startimage=http%3A//www.mywebsite.com/IM/CommercialTacTilesJan2014.jpg" />
```

There are probably other parameters that have to be done like this as well and embedded into the FlashVars in a long string. I noticed there were several other params that were not working - but at least I got it figured out.